# I don't want to remove stop words by splitting words into letters

Tags: java, servlets, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am writing this piece of code to remove stop words from my text.

**Problem - This code works perfectly for removing stopwords but the problem arises when words like ant, ide is present in my text as it removes both words ant and ide because ant is present in important, want and ide is present in side.** But I don't want to split words into a letter to remove stopwords.

```
            String sCurrentLine;
            List<String> stopWordsofwordnet=new ArrayList<>();
            FileReader fr=new FileReader("G:\\stopwords.txt");
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stopWordsofwordnet.add(sCurrentLine);
                }
                //out.println("<br>"+stopWordsofwordnet);
            List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            String text = request.getParameter("textblock");
            text=text.trim().replaceAll("[\\s,;]+", " ");
            String[] words = text.split(" ");

//            wordsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
                for (String word : words) {
                wordsList.add(word);
                }
            out.println("<br>");

            //remove stop words here from the temp list
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsList.size(); i++) 
            {
            // get the item as string
            for (int j = 0; j < stopWordsofwordnet.size(); j++) 
            {
            if (stopWordsofwordnet.get(j).contains(wordsList.get(i).toLowerCase())) 
            {
                out.println(wordsList.get(i)+"&nbsp;");
                wordsList.remove(i);
                i--;
                break;
            }
            }
            }
            out.println("<br>");
            for (String str : wordsList) {
            out.print(str+" ");
            }
```

Comment: If you don't want stop word `"ant"` to remove word `"want"`, why did you use `contains()`?

Comment: okayyy.. then how should I write it? Please tell

Comment: Replace `contains` with `equals`

Comment: ok.. thank you it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated, and can be reduced to this:

```java
// Load stop words from file
Set<String> stopWords = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
stopWords.addAll(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("G:\\stopwords.txt")));

// Get text and split into words
String text = request.getParameter("textblock");
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        text.replaceAll("[\\s,;]+", " ").trim().split(" ")));

// Remove stop words from list of words
wordsList.removeAll(stopWords);
```

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting error in TreeSet even after writing the import statement.

Comment: @SnehilRSingh `import java.nio.file.*; import java.util.*;` --- I can't help more than that without knowing what error you get.

Comment: Yaa I have written the same import statement but still, I was getting a red line under TreeSet but the code was running fine, restarting the Netbeans helped for me (weird). Thanks for your help @Andreas.

Comment: Can you help me with identifying slang words in a text using java?

Comment: @SnehilRSingh If you need help with that, you should create a new question, *after* first research on the web to see if there is already a solution available out there.